# Showing popup image on hover and click

Tags: leaflet, geojson, leaflet-draw

I want to to show an image when the mouse hovers on a marker or polygon, and on click show a popup with property attributes information from GeoJSON.

I can manage to show attributes on click but I am not able to show image on hover. 
However, the image can be viewed in console.log but it's not appearing on the screen.

Below is what I want it to look like.

[image]

Comment: I want to show an Image in mouse hover on each marker, polygon, and polyline.
I find solution for popup window with more information.

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution. Hope this will help someone who is searching for a similar question.

The code is:

```
    popupContent = document.createElement("img");
    popupContent.onload = function () {
      layer.openPopup();
    };
    popupContent.src = "path/to/image";
    layer.bindPopup(popupContent, {
      maxWidth: "auto"

});
```

Copied content from http://jsfiddle.net/3v7hd2vx/32/

```
var map = L.map("map");
L.tileLayer("http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png").addTo(map);

map.setView([48.85, 2.35], 12);

var marker, popupContent;

for (var i = 0; i < 1; i += 1) {
    marker = L.marker([48.85, 2.35]).addTo(map);
  popupContent = document.createElement("img");
  popupContent.onload = function () {
    marker.openPopup();
  };
  popupContent.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/75/Stack_Exchange_logo_and_wordmark.svg/375px-Stack_Exchange_logo_and_wordmark.svg.png";
  //popupContent = '<img src="http://c4.staticflickr.com/1/691/21131215939_49601d06ef_b.jpg" />';
  marker.bindPopup(popupContent, {
    maxWidth: "auto"
  });
}

marker.openPopup();
```

For reference : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38170366/leaflet-adjust-popup-to-picture-size